# React Native : shadows behavior

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, shadow

Hello React Native developers,

The code below produces the image in caption. I'm just wondering why the shadow of the first view (with the icon) is diminished compared to the black view. I added visible borders so you can see the difference between the two shadows. The "issue" both applies to Android & iOS platforms.
Is this really an issue or this is just normal behavior ?

```js
<>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            marginTop: 50,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 1,
            shadowRadius: 16.0,
            borderRadius: 1000,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}>
          <Icon name="cog" type="ionicons" color="black" size={50} />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            marginTop: 50,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 1,
            shadowRadius: 16.0,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            borderRadius: 1000,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
        />
</>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some function in React Native shadow works badly. Try to use https://github.com/SrBrahma/react-native-shadow-2 instead.

```js
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-shadow-2';

<Shadow>
  <Text style={{ margin: 20, fontSize: 20 }}></Text>
</Shadow>
```

[image]